# Why Angular 2 http don't reach Asp.NET MVC Controller

Tags: angular

I have copied the Angular2 tour of heroes project to my asp.net mvc project.
Everything Ok but when I change a line in hero.service.ts also hero.service.js

private heroesUrl = 'app/heroes';  // URL to web API

to my controller/action and I break point there.

the Angular 2 http never reach my controller/action

Please help me solve this problem.

Thank.

Comment: If you publish a link to the plunker and also your controller code that might help.

Comment: Can you please share more code? usually if you are calling web api then your path must in this format - `http.get("api/heros")` where api controller name is herosController.

Comment: are they running on the same port? I've created a CustomRequestOptions class that overrides the baseUrl.

Comment: Do you know for sure client sends request actual to the server with heroesUrl?

I ported "Tour of Heroes" tutorial to MVC Core: https://github.com/yfranz/angular2-heroes-with-mvc-core-net

It may give you some ideas.